# condition for a bivector to be simple

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

If $B$ is a bivector and $x$ is a vector, I have to prove that

> Bivector $B$ is simple with $x$ (i.e. there's some vector $y$ such that $B=x\wedge y$) iff $B\wedge x = 0$

Now, for necessity part:

$B = x\wedge y \Longrightarrow B\wedge x=x\wedge y\wedge x=0$ (for definition of outer product)

And I'm stuck on the converse part.

Comment: Note that the converse as stated is false.  Indeed, suppose that $x = 0$.  Then $B \wedge x = 0$ for all $B$, including non-zero $B$, but non-zero $B$ cannot be written as $x\wedge y$ for any $y$.  So I assume you want the case when $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $B \wedge x = 0$, then $Bx^{-1} = B \cdot x^{-1}$ is some vector.  $Bx^{-1} x = B$ on the one hand, but using a different associative grouping for the geometric product, you get $(B x^{-1}) \wedge x$ instead.  Hence, $y = -Bx^{-1}$.

Comment: What is the inverse of a vector?

Comment: The inverse of any nonzero blade $K$ under the geometric product is $K^{-1} = K^\dagger/(KK^\dagger)$, where $K^\dagger$ is the reverse. This is a well-defined quantity.  The expression $KK^\dagger$ is a scalar and hence the division does not care about being on the left or right.  For a vector, this reduces to $x^{-1} = x/(xx) = x/x^2 = x/|x|^2$.

Comment: OK.  I assume the dot product is defined linearly by $(y\wedge z)\cdot x = \pm \bigl( (y\cdot x)\wedge z - (z\cdot x)\wedge y\bigr)$, and you've chosen an inner product (also to define the adjoint).  Where do you use that $B\wedge x = 0$?  Or is there something in the word "geometric product" that I'm missing?

Comment: Ah, so I finally read over http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra, based on the tags in the original post.

Comment: Yes, the sign in this case would be $-(y \cdot x) z + (z \cdot x) y$.  The key point in my answer is that the geometric product $Bx^{-1}$ is a linear combination of terms of two different grades, having a vector part and a trivector part.  Setting $B \wedge x = 0$ determines that the trivector part of $Bx^{-1}$ is also zero (it's just denoted $B \wedge x^{-1})$.  From there, the associativity of the geometric product allows us to reason that $B x^{-1} x = B$ and yet is also equal to $(Bx^{-1} )\wedge x$.